# How to extract pure carbon dioxide from sodium bicarbonate?

Tags: aqueous-solution

What are the most commonly-used methods for extracting carbon dioxide gas from an aqueous solution of sodium bicarbonate?

Several industrial "Carbon Capture" plants today are able to extract carbon dioxide from unadulterated air by passing it through an aqueous solution of sodium hydroxide ($\ce{NaOH}$) to produce an aqueous solution also containing sodium bicarbonate. There's plenty of information on the internet about this step, and it's straight forward.

What's less straight forward is how the aqueous solution with $\ce{NaHCO3}$ is later reacted to produce a pure carbon dioxide.

How can carbon dioxide gas be purified from this Direct Carbon Capture (DCC) process using an aqueous solution of sodium hydroxide ($\ce{NaOH}$)?

Comment: Heating will do. You won't get your NaOH back, though.

Comment: Regrettably, though it is *possible* to capture CO2, energetically, it is impractical because the heat to regenerate the NaOH would expend *huge* amounts of fuel, generating far more CO2.

Comment: Sadly, I think I'm being downvoted because I used the word "Carbon Capture." To be clear, I'm not talking about DCC as a means to avert the climate crisis. I'm purely interested in the chemical process to collect pure Carbon Dioxide as environmentally friendly as possible for later use in a Sabatier Reactor. It's hard to imagine a more sustainable way to create CO2 than pulling it out of the air with a bit of NaCl & water.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield The question is being voted for closure due lack of details and clarity. That directly applies to the fact you have not clearly stated the background or context of your question in the question body. I suggest you move the esential content of your comment to the question, eventually more elaborated.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any verification of an industrial plant using this technology. The closest seems to be the plants in development by Carbon Engineering, which are planned to use a potassium hydroxide solution for the carbon dioxide capture step.

Their proposed process then precipitates the carbon from solution by addition of calcium hydroxide, yielding solid calcium carbonate. The $\ce{CO2}$ is liberated from the calcium carbonate by heating in a traditional calcination process such as is used in cement manufacture. This step is fueled by natural gas combustion.

In summary:

1. $\ce{CO2(g) + HO- (aq) + K+ (aq) -> HCO3- (aq) + K+ (aq)}$
2. $\ce{CaO (s) + HCO3- (aq) + K+ (aq) -> CaCO3(s) + K+ (aq) + HO- (aq)}$
3. $\ce{CaCO3 (s) + heat -> CaO(s) + CO2 (g)}$

This is described on the Carbon Engineering website [here](https://carbonengineering.com/our-technology/).

Comment: Yes, a technical answer to the question but with respect to the provided clarification:  "I'm purely interested in the chemical process to collect pure Carbon Dioxide as environmentally friendly as possible for later use in a Sabatier Reactor", the process  outlined in the provided answer involving "a traditional calcination process" is hardly "environmentally friendly", albeit, interesting info.

Comment: Further, since some are seeking a technically strict answer here, this provided answer does not address the question relating to either NaHCO3 or NaOH, or even a mention thereof. MODERATOR, where are you?

Comment: @AJKOER -  the difference between an aqueous solution of sodium bicarb and a solution of potassium bicarb does not qualitatively affect the described process, so this does provide an answer to a process that could be implemented. As for "environmentally friendly", without a definition of that term, I can only say that the main complaint against calcination as I understand it is the CO2 produced, which in this case is captured along with that from air. Some may consider that to be environmentally friendly, though some may not.

Comment: Hi all, I'm here - @AJKOER, please use a flag to get a mod.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133317/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-how-to-extract-pure-carbon-dioxide-from-sodium-bi).